# VS2013 Publish using WebDeploy isn't transforming additional files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I've build simple WebAPI project and not i'm trying to publish it using Visual Studio 2013 build in Publish mechanism (BUILD>Publish)
I've pick Web Deploy as publish method, got everything working, except transform files.

I have Web.config and Settings.config and two transforms for each.
When I do standard build on my project inside bin folder I see single Web.config and Settings.config with transform applied, but when I do publish instead of transformed Settings.config file I see one without transforms applied.

I't looks like publish mechanism inside Visual Studio is only transforming Web.config and it skips additional files.

Below is part of my csproj that is responsible for applying transforms:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <TransformXml Condition="Exists('Settings.$(Configuration).config')" Source="Settings.config" Destination="$(OutputPath)Settings.config" Transform="Settings.$(Configuration).config" />
  <TransformXml Condition="Exists('Web.$(Configuration).config')" Source="Web.config" Destination="$(OutputPath)Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" />
</Target>
```

My question is how should I setup my publish profile so instead of copying clean Settings.config it will apply correct transform and publish it.

EDIT:
I've managed to find one thing that might help solving this. If I add `UseMsdeployExe` to pubxml I can see in Output that my Settings.config is transformed and saved to `bin` folder, but then later is it overridden by original file.

my AfterBuild target is called correctly, but after it I can see in output those lines:

2>    Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.
2>    Copying bin\Api.dll to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Api.dll.
2>    Copying Settings.config to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Settings.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SlowCheetah to transform the files, it will handle the deployment for you.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah

Comment: Sorry for such late reply. I've tried `SlowCheetah` but it isn't transforming appSettings located in separate file (<appSettings configSource="Settings.config" />). I've added transforms, but when I try to preview them nothing changes.

Comment: Can you provide samples of your appSettings and transforms?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, but it looks like it works fine. I just created new project and tried SlowCheetah and everything worked fine. In my case problem was I had installed two similar extensions `Configuration Transform` and `SlowCheetah`. I've uninstalled first and now everything works fine. Sadly this isn't build in, but hopefully soon will - https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2043217-support-web-config-style-transforms-on-any-file-in

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!